# Find function that maximize a integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, optimization, definite-integrals, calculus-of-variations

Let $x\in [0,1]$ and arbitrary positive function $f(x)>C>0$. My question is how to find a function $A(x)\in [0,1]$ in order to maximize the integral below:
$$\int_{0}^{1} A(x)\,d\,ln\,f(x)$$

Any direction or thoughts (e.g. adding more constrains to $A(x)$) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think $\ln f(x)$ is of bounded variation so this integral may not make sense.

Comment: Let's take more stringent assumption then in order to make the problem valid

Comment: @probably_someone The problem clearly says $A(x) \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did more research on the topic and thinking this is related to a more general solution named as Euler-Lagrange equation. Basically $A(x)$ can possibly be found by searching the stationary points of its functional. I will provide more constructive answer if I can think through this.